# two words and blank spaces not working in MYSQL query using LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql-like

i'm making a searcher for my site and this works fine with one word querys

```
 $consulta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recetas WHERE (titulo LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR intro LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR extra LIKE '%$busqueda%') ORDER BY id DESC");
```

But if i type 'two words' it doesn't give me result, `$busqueda` it's result from a `<input/>` given through `$_POST['TERM']`

any idea what i'm missing?

SOLVED

i was missing to encode the variable to URI... oops haha THANKS!

Comment: are you sure what you are typing exists in database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of how your query will look at the end:

```
Select ... where '%two words%. ...
```

If you want to search for words like that, you'll have to massage the data to look more  like:

```
 ... Like '%two%words%'
 ... Like '%two%' or like '%words%'
```

depending on your exact search requirements

Comment: i'll try to implode with % and let you know. usefull, thanks!

Comment: Your syntax is wrong, it's not Like '%two%' or like '%words%'   it should be like this :
LIKE '%two%' or '%words%'

Answer (score 2):

Unless the two words are adjacent in the text, the LIKE operator won't find them.  You may want to use [full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

In order to find two non-contiguous words, the input would need to be split up into two separate values and the query would have to look something like this:

```
WHERE (titulo LIKE '%$word1%' OR intro LIKE '%$word1%' OR extra LIKE '%$word1%' OR
       titulo LIKE '%$word2%' OR intro LIKE '%$word2%' OR extra LIKE '%$word2%' )
```

That is assuming you want a match with either word.  If both must match, then something like this:

```
WHERE (titulo LIKE '%$word1%' AND titulo like '%$word2%' OR
       intro LIKE '%$word1%' AND intro LIKE '%$word2%'  OR 
       extra LIKE '%$word1%' AND extra LIKE '%$word2%' )
```

And one other thing. It would be better to use parameterized queries to avoid an [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score -2):

where ( MATCH( titulo, intro, extra) AGAINST ('word1 word2' in BOOLEAN MODE))

Comment: ani coment about it? i could add that but i don't understand it... :$

Comment: This answer is of very low quality as is just some code without any explanation about it. It is to be removed.