# search partial string with white spaces in mysql

Tags: mysql

My table structure is like this

```
products_options_id  | products_options_values_name  |
       544127        | Silver 925 Chains as per Gram |
```

this is my table structure but for search dynamically  I have only "Silver 925 Chains" for search in this colomn But I got empty result set.

```
SELECT * FROM `products_options_values`
WHERE `products_options_values_name` LIKE '%Silver 925 Chains%'
```

Is there any other way to search partial string

Comment: Is the column called products_options_values_name or products_options_values?

Comment: it is products_options_values_name

Comment: if this table utilize myisam engine then use full text search, that is more effective, but in your case, can you provide more info as it might be no. of space are different in search string and stored striing

Comment: Could you please try this : `SELECT * FROM products_options_values
WHERE REPLACE(products_options_values_name,' ','') LIKE REPLACE('%Silver 925 Chains%',' ','');` Just a wild guess: Maybe more than one space between two words.

Comment: May [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4617467/5847906) help?

Comment: Boolean fulltext search compared with like an basic pattern matching in this SO topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39467443/full-text-search-result-similar-to-mysql-like-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this, hope it will help you

```
SELECT * FROM `products_options_values`
WHERE MATCH(products_options_values_name)  AGAINST ('Silver 925 Chains' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```